# How can I clean up this SELECT query?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, user-defined-functions

I'm running PHP 5 and MySQL 5 on a dedicated server (Ubuntu Server 8.10) with full root access.  I'm cleaning up some LAMP code I've inherited and I've a large number of SQL selects with this type of construct:

```
SELECT ... FROM table WHERE
  LCASE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    strSomeField, ' ', '-'), ',', ''), '/', '-'), '&', ''), '+', '')
  ) = $somevalue
```

Ignoring the fact that the database should never have been constructed to require such a select in the first place, and the $somevalue field will need to be parameterised to plug the gaping security hole, what is my best option for fixing the WHERE condition into something less offensive?  If I was using MSSQL or Oracle I'd simply put together a user-defined function, but my experience with MySQL is more limited and I've not constructed a UDF with it before, although I'm happy coding C.

*Update:* For all those who've already raised their eyebrows at this in the original code, $somevalue is actually something like $GET['product']—there are a few variations on the theme. In this case the select is pulling the product back from the database by product name—after stripping out characters so it matches what could be previously passed as a URI parameter.

Comment: has this been submitted to http://thedailywtf.com/ yet?

Comment: That code is ADORABLE! My 5 year old son knows better ways of preventing SQL injection.

Comment: Can you do the reverse transformation to the searching value? Maybe this can be part of a process to make all the entries consistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is my best option for fixing the WHERE condition into something less offensive?

Do the replace in the application layer, there is no call for that logic to be in the database. Make it a plain old PHP function.

ETA: argh, I see what you mean. You're stuffed then, all that's left is “the fact that the database should never have been constructed to require such a select in the first place”! :-) You *could* move the REPLACE out to a stored production ([CREATE FUNCTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html))... that would certainly make the query look nicer, but it's kind of sweeping the problem under the carpet really as it still requires the whole table be scanned and processed to make the SELECT query. I don't think you can do a lot better without changing the schema, sorry.

(I'm guessing this is a function to get a ‘cleaned’ ID-style token from a text title? Normally you'd indeed do that in a plain old PHP function, and store it as a separate column from the ‘real’ title. Then you can select it easily, and index it for performance.)

Comment: How? given that the replace functions are applied against the field in the database, not the PHP variable

Comment: +1, alter table to add filter column and run update with this replace fot all table once. also add replace on insert new records.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the regular expression library:

- http://forge.mysql.com/projects/project.php?id=86
- http://udf-regexp.php-baustelle.de/trac/

Specifically:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE?(text, pattern, replace ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear, that's a fun one. Here's a summary of what it does to strSomeField:

- spaces and forward slashes become hyphens
- commas, ampersands, and plus-signs are removed
- converted to lowercase

This can't be easily done in MySQL without adding in the regexp_replace user-defined function that MarkusQ linked, which I believe will require recompliation of MySQL.

Do you have the option of simply processing all the data in the table so that this isn't necessary? Create a PHP script to select all the values in strSomeField, perform the same processing as I summarized above, and update the rows with the new values. Or will this break other parts of the application?

Answer (score 0):

If you do create a new field with a preprocessed strSomeField column, you should add a trigger that automatically updates it if strSomeField changes. Might eliminate some headaches.

Answer (score 0):

> after stripping out characters so it
>   matches what could be previously
>   passed as a URI parameter.

Oh. Same pitfall again and again.

**Do not use product name as a key!**

Don't you think SO authors are less experienced than you?
But look at the SO question url:
stackoverflow.com/questions/**587422**/how-can-i-clean-up-this-select-query
They use a numeric key and the rest just for decoration.
So, name can be edited at any time but the page will remain the same. And sure, no problems like yours one.

It's not database problem. It's design problem. Fault I'd say.

Comment: Yes, in the end I just swept it under the carpet using a function because actually fixing it properly breaks *everything*. The whole system uses a single giant God class and is full of holes like this - at least it's less offensive to look at now and reads cleaner.